# i'm using 2 queries is there any way to make it single query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

here is my situation,

i'm obtaining `id`  from `superadmin` table where `role=2`

like this

```
SELECT id FROM superadmin WHERE role='2'
```

suppose i will get 10 records

```
    id
----------------   
    3

    4

    6

    8

    10

    14

    16
    .
    .
```

i need to pass them into `2nd table`  like this

```
SELECT status FROM categorydata WHERE users='id'  // above id on each iteration
```

here is my code in PHP:

```
$query_super_admin = $obj->queryAll("SELECT id FROM superadmin WHERE role='2'");
  foreach($query_super_admin['results'] as $result){
            $user_id = $result['id'];
             $category_related = $obj->queryAll("SELECT status FROM categorydata WHERE users='".$user_id."'"); 

// result data

}
```

**QUESTION:** i want to achieve this with `sql` is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

TRY THIS : I think `INNER JOIN` will perform better in this case

```
SELECT c.status
from superadmin s
inner join categorydata c on s.id = c.users
where s.role='2'
```

Answer (score 1):

The following query will retrieve users along with their statuses:

```
SELECT s.id, c.status
FROM superadmin s
LEFT JOIN categorydata c ON s.id = c.users
WHERE s.role = 2
ORDER BY s.id;
```

I use a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN like Suraz because you may be interested in getting users with no status associated.

Then in PHP, to get the same behavior as your initial code, you can do as follows:

```
$query = <<<EOQ
SELECT s.id, c.status
FROM superadmin s
LEFT JOIN categorydata c ON s.id = c.users
WHERE s.role = 2
ORDER BY s.id;
EOQ;

$query_super_admin = $obj->queryAll($query);
$cur_id = -1;
foreach($query_super_admin['results'] as $result) {
  if ($result['id'] != $cur_id) {
    // This is a new user id
    // Do whatever you want here, like printing user id, name, etc.

    $cur_id = $result['id'];
  }

  if (!$result['status']) {
    continue; // No status associated to this user
  }

  // Do whatever you want here, like printing status
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WHERE IN (...)`:

```
SELECT status
FROM categorydata
WHERE users IN (SELECT id FROM superadmin WHERE role = '2')
```